# Netty - can not write to channel at registration (channelRegistered event)

Tags: java, server, client, netty, channel

I've encountered a problem concerning sending packets at channel registration (Client -> Server).
To test furthermore, if I send the packet after the registration, I am allowed to send the packet.
The opposite way (Server -> Client) works totally fine.
Registration function:

```
@Override
public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.channel().write(new byte[] {0x00});
}
```

It also encounters an encoder down the filter chain:

```
public class Encoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<byte[]>{

@Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, byte[] b, ByteBuf bb) throws Exception {
    byte[] data = b.getData();

    bb.writeInt(data.length);
    bb.writeBytes(data);
}
}
```

The server therefore does not receive the aforementioned packet - as a result,
I debugged to see if channelRead event fired and it did not. (Neither did my decode class to decode the data)

Any assumptions ?

Answer (score 1):

`channelRegistered` is called when the channel is registered to it's EventLoop. That does not imply it is ready to send data yet, the channel hasn't even opened a socket yet.
You want `channelActive`, which is called when the channel is active, i.e. ready to send and receive data.

Comment: I see, I guess I shouldn't have rushed and read the API description, thank you for enlightening me :)